# How do I count the number of words in a word document (.doc / .docx) when a user uploads it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to count the number of words in a document uploaded to my application. I don't want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll's because I don't access to my server to install Word application.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is the documents uploaded? to ftp server or database?

Comment: I think you're asking "How do I count the number of words in a word document (.doc / .docx) when a user uploads it?" Is that correct?

Comment: To Ftp... @AnupSharma

Comment: Checkout using http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124), the following code should work:

```
int words;
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
{
  words = (int) document.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Words.Text;
}
```

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.extendedproperties.properties.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer but This piece of code does not work properly... for example i try to count "this is a test project" this must return 5 but i give 3...

Comment: Checkout https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/69639b01-6127-4d30-b385-7bdbdbf9a0bc/wrong-values-trying-to-read-words-count-from-a-microsoft-word-document-with-openxml?forum=oxmlsdk for some ideas